# Is it possible to stitch a L2VPN connection into a VPLS domain on Juniper MX

Tags: juniper, mpls, vpls, l2vpn

I'm trying to connect one end of a L2VPN tunnel to a VPLS instance on a Juniper MX router. The L2VPN should act like a local interface in the VPLS instance. Is this possible at all? I can't find any information about how this could be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it seems the way to go is to use a logical tunnel interface on MX. Just put one end of the lt Interface in the VPLS instance and the other end in the L2VPN instance:

```
lt-1/2/0 {
        mtu 1514;
        unit 0 {
            encapsulation ethernet-ccc;
            peer-unit 1;
            family ccc;
        }
        unit 1 {
            encapsulation ethernet-vpls;
            peer-unit 0;
        }
 }
```

This will stitch the L2VPN to the VPLS instance.